# Does air dissolve in the R-113 (i.e. Freon 113)?

Tags: solubility

Can anyone tell me whether or not air or N$_2$ dissolves easily in the R-113 (liquid solvent) under the saturation pressure of R-113? If yes, what is the solubility roughly? From [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1,1,2-Trichloro-1,2,2-trifluoroethane) one can only find its solubility in water. 
It will be better if you could provide a link. Thank you in advance!

PS: In Table V of [this data](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdfplus/10.1021/cr60242a003?src=recsys) provided by @Jon Custer, I found no solubility data for air (or N_$2$) dissolved in R-113.

Comment: Well, solubility wouldn't be as good as in perfluorocarbons, but it may be tough to get specific data.

Comment: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdfplus/10.1021/cr60242a003?src=recsys has data...

Comment: @Mithoron a little irrelevant... I knew R113 is a chlorofluorocarbon. Did you mean chlorofluorocarbon $\in$ perfluorocarbon or perfluorocarbon $\in$ chlorofluorocarbon or chlorofluorocarbon $=$ perfluorocarbon?

Comment: @JonCuster thank you, sir. I checked Table 5 in that article. But there seems no solubility data of air or N$_2$ in R113 (liquid solvent).

Comment: @JonCuster I mean all fluor beats half-chloro/half-fluoro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While data for air solubility in R-113 is difficult to find, Henry's law constants $k_\text{H}$ are available for $\ce{N2}$ in a series of related refrigerants (Ref. 1) comprised of variously halogenated ethanes. However, these are predicted, not experimental, Henry's law constants: the vapor-liquid equilibrium of binary mixtures containing nitrogen was modeled with an equation-of-state based on a perturbed–Chain (PC) modification of the Statistical Associating Fluid Theory (SAFT). I back-calculated the $k_\text{H}$ from the published temperature coefficients. Assuming a $\ce{N2}$ partial pressure $\pu{p_{\ce{N2}}= 0.78 atm}$ then leads to the following $\ce{N2}$ solubilities (as mole fractions) in the refrigerants in the temperature range $\pu{170-280 K}$:

[image]

Evidently the solubilities are generally below $\pu{0.02 mol \%}$, which I believe would qualify as "not high" but not negligible ($\chi=1\times 10^{-4}$ corresponds to $\pu{\approx 1 mM}$ solution concentration).

After more careful examination, I found that Vinš et al. cite a publication by Huang et al. (Ref. 2) which compares simulation and experimental (Ref. 3) Henry's law constants for $\ce{N2}$ in R-113, the value at 298 K being $\pu{k_H= 52.5 MPa}$. This is larger than the values above, which are in the range $\pu{1-15 MPa}$. Since $p_\ce{N2} = k_\text{H} \chi_\ce{N2}$, the larger $k_\text{H}$ for R-113 means nitrogen is even less soluble in this refrigerant.

Note of course the analysis here is restricted to nitrogen, but you can proceed in the same way to analyze other gases for which $k_\text{H}$ are reported.

*References*

1. Vinš, V., Hruby, J., Solubility of nitrogen in one-component refrigerants: Prediction by PC-SAFT EoS and a correlation of Henry’s law constants. International Journal of Refrigeration, 34, 2109-2117 (2011).
2. Huang, Y.L., Miroshnichenko, S., Hasse, H., Vrabec, J., Henry's Law Constant from Molecular Simulation: A Systematic Study of 95 Systems. Int. J. Thermophys. 30, 1791–1810 (2009).
3. H. Hiraoka, J. H. Hildebrand, J. Phys. Chem. 68, 213 (1964).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In the plot, there appears no curve for R113? What is $k_H$ and $T_r$? Most importantly, did you predict that N$_2$ should be not easily dissolved in saturated R113?

Comment: @user55777 I updated my answer to address your question.